# Sublime Text won't execute .py

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm trying tu run a .py file from sublime text by pressing ctrl + b. The console opens, but nothing happens. I'm using Python 3.3. I've set my path to python and I've set my build system to python in sublime text. (also I've saved my file, and in cmd it works) What can be the problem?

Comment: should your script output something?  What happens in the terminal?  Does it show the `[Finished in 0.0s]` message?

Comment: I've saved my file, and if I compile it from cmd, it will run perfectly.

Comment: go to prefrences->brousepackages->python->python.sublime-build open it with sublime text and please tell whats written there

Comment: {
    "cmd": ["C:\\python33\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}

Comment: the only issue could be the path to python check if its correct path "C:\\python33\\python.exe" i am on mac so cant give you path but its a path issue

Comment: Ok try chainging path to "C:/python33/python" but do not do it in the same build make a custom build in user  copy you python.sublime-build paste it in user make changes you can also create new build settings

Comment: Make sure you've chosen the build system you want to use via `Tools -> Build System -> PythonCustom` (or whatever you named your new build system you saved in the `Packages/User` directory).

Comment: Already did (I'm not THAT stupid :D)

Comment: My `python.sublime-build` file contains the same thing as yours, and it works for me. If sublime wasn't finding the Python interpreter, there would be an error message to that effect (`The system cannot find the file specified`).