# Can't run Python in Sublime Text 2 anymore

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm trying to run Python in Sublime Text 2. I usually just press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to run it but now I'm getting this error:

```
Error trying to parse build system: No data in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/JSLint/JSLint.sublime-build:1:1
```

Which is JavaScript related. What's happening here and how do I fix it? :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314694/sublime-text-wont-execute-py

Comment: If you look at `Tools -> Build System`, is it set to `Automatic`?

Comment: Oh thanks! That solved the issue. I had saved the file as a .py file so I just assumed sublime would automatically figure that out.